# How to make a page print to printer just once

Tags: php, javascript, plugins, printing, browser

I have a basic html page generated through php and it prints to a printer after a link click using Ben Nadel's print [plugin](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm). However, I don't want the user to print the page again. I tried setting the 'print' link to a negative z-index using jquery after it's being clicked, but the user can refresh the page and reuse the link so it would print again. I also know that I can somehow disable the refresh feature, by modifying what F5 does, but that would't save the day since the user can refresh the page through the url bar, and I can't remove/hide, it as much as I know. It also runs on localhost so the user client and server are on the same side. Even the browser doesn't matter since I could use the one that fits this case.

Comment: What are you trying do hide/print only once? Maybe there is a better solution to this issue. -- Denying printing is a tough one, I have no clue how this could work out. -- Is this the same content for every user or can you just "delete" it after printing once?

Comment: 1)I was talking about removing/hiding the url bar, but I don't think it's possible at all, even if I popup a new window. 2)The content is not the same for all users since it is php generated and it needs to be 'thrown' away after just one print job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And I am not sure the requirement to print only once makes sense: a clever user may print into a PDF printer, and print on paper the "printed" PDF many times. A novice user may legitimately want to print twice or more (e.g. because he sent the printing to the wrong printer).

Comment: Yep. Or use the browser's File | Print menu and ignore the print link entirely. Or choose to print multiple copies in the print dialog box. This is browser DRM for printing. It's not possible.

Comment: The content of the page comes from php so it's different each time it's generated. If a user saved the pdf and printed that static information everytime they wanted, it wouldn't be a problem since it would have no further value because it must be unique.

Comment: So you don't need to bother programmatically about prohibit many printings. It probably would be simpler to add a small message for the novice user reminding him that the information will become stale when used.

Comment: I just thought it would be fancier to solve the problem the dynamic way. 'It probably would be simpler to add a small message for the novice user reminding him that the information will become stale when used'- I hate those static messages!:P However thanks, i might consider that idea even against my will.

Comment: Well, as a web user, I hate pseudo-fancy sites which disable me doing something natural. So we disagree! :-)